# Exact Target 500 Server Error Post-Form Fill

Tags: ampscript

[image]I have created a CloudPage with a form that writes to a data extension, form renders with no problems, but on submission of the data, Google Chrome dev console shows a 500 server error, no errors are shown in ExactTarget.

CloudPage can be found at https://pub.s1.exacttarget.com/lfdm2ttmhoc

This page was built using the new Content Builder within ExactTarget. It does not happen to every form submit.

I am not familiar with AmpScript and suspect that is the issue.

```
%%[
```

var @LastName, @FirstName, @Title, @CompanyName, @EmailAddress, @PhoneNumber, @Allergies, @ICEName, @ICEPhone, @ICERelationship, @FutureCommOptIn, @PhotoRecordOptIn, @createDeRecord, @curtime

set @LastName = RequestParameter("LastName")
set @FirstName = RequestParameter("FirstName")
set @Title = RequestParameter("Title")
set @EmailAddress = RequestParameter("EmailAddress")
set @CompanyName = RequestParameter("CompanyName")
set @PhoneNumber = RequestParameter("PhoneNumber")
set @Allergies = RequestParameter("Allergies")
set @ICEName = RequestParameter("ICEName")
set @ICEPhone = RequestParameter("ICEPhone")
set @ICERelationship = RequestParameter("ICERelationship")
set @FutureCommOptIn = RequestParameter("FutureCommOptIn")
set @PhotoRecordOptIn = RequestParameter("PhotoRecordOptIn")
set @curtime = xtshortdate

if RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted" then

set @createDeRecord = UpsertDE(
    "HMHS - Conference",
     1,"LastName",@LastName,
     "FirstName",@FirstName,
     "Title",@Title,
     "EmailAddress",@EmailAddress,
     "PhoneNumber",@PhoneNumber,
     "Allergies",@Allergies,
     "ICEName",@ICEName,
     "ICEPhone",@ICEPhone,
     "ICERelationship",@ICERelationship,
     "FutureCommOptIn",@FutureCommOptIn,
     "PhotoRecordOptIn",@PhotoRecordOptIn,
     "CompanyName",@CompanyName,
     "DateSubmitted",@curtime
)
endif

]%%

Comment: Hi. Please post AMPscript that you used in CloudPages and the Data Extension details, like all the attribute names, types and such.

Comment: @Atheri I updated the original post with image and code. Thanks for looking. I also tweeted Marketing Cloud Support.